# V-Calendar - Use from CDN - Vue 3.2

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vcalendar

Looking to upgrade v-calendar to vue 3.2 and we currently use the CDN installation method as described in
[https://vcalendar.io/getting-started/installation.html]

The current version of the CDN seems to be a 2.x version of V-calendar with all the issues with mixins. Is there a version 3 or has anybody got a CDN version working on Vue 3.2 ?

I have checked the source and cannot seen a CDN version

Comment: v-calendar has a `next` branch ... https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/tree/next ... possibly not available on CDN - so you'll have to use their release - note, that link seems to be for 3.0.0-alpha8, yet in my project, I have v-calendar 3.0.3 - https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/tree/v3.0.3

Comment: oh, wait, jsdelivr has 3.0.3 ... https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/v-calendar?tab=files&version=3.0.3 - also unpkg (as per the docs you linked) - see https://unpkg.com/browse/v-calendar@3.0.3/dist/